# Ubuntu process killed every specific time

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and at 17 minutes every hour, all the processes are suddenly killed. When I type " dmesg -T| grep -E -i -B100 'killed process' ", then nothing is come up.

I'm testing with very very light process about python like

```
while True:
  print('a')
  time.sleep(2)
```

But this process also killed when 17 minutes every hour.

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Is this e.g. some sort of shared hosting box, or your own desktop machine, or a server you manage?

Comment: Time to upgrade: we're up to 21.04 now.

Comment: @duffymo Is this the canonical way to give users a kind nudge to upgrade?

Comment: @AKX Server I manage..

Comment: @duffymo 18.04 is a still supported LTS version.

Comment: Check your crontabs, your systemd timers, etc. Processes aren't killed on a schedule for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly if it's 17 minutes past the hour, every hour, regardless of reboots and without drifting earlier or later, it's almost certainly a crontab somewhere; "crontab" is the standard mechanism for running jobs regularly.

Since it's specifically 17 minutes past the hour, check in `/etc/cron.hourly` first, since those scripts are run 17 minutes past the hour on standard Ubuntu.

Secondly, check in `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d` and `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Comment: Unknown process in path /etc/cron.hourly..!! When I delete it, everything goes normal. Thanks a lot!!